# VBA Replace() doesn't replace characters

Tags: vba, replace

This is odd. In the code below the replace() does not replace the : character. Why? How do I fix this? Even if I switch ":" with chr(58) it doesn't work.

```
Dim dispName as String
dispName = "     110531 Re：Our file 027-10.doc"
dispName = Replace(dispName, ":", " ")
msgbox dispName
```

Comment: Codes workes for me fine with Excel 2007

Comment: look at your `:`, it looks like that is not the same as the other one

Comment: @Katz You are right :)

Comment: So weird - VBA identifies both with chr() as 58. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code as it is to notepad++ and found that used both ':' characters are different.

Change both to the same and run the code